# How to restore Firefox icon in Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: firefox

I have upgraded my Ubuntu desktop using the following command,

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

After that my Firefox version gets changed into 10.0. For some reason we have run our softwares in Firefox version 3.6. So i have removed the Firefox by using the following command.

`sudo apt-get remove --purge firefox` and reinstalled Firefox but again 10.0 got installed. So i have removed it again. And i have downloaded tar.gz file and extracted it. The same is working fine, however my old Firefox shortcuts icons were simply showing without default Firefox icon. How to bring it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You use Gnome, just click right mouse button on the panel and add activator. Point it to Your firefox executable, and name it firefox. It should take firefox icon automatically.

Comment: What you mean by activator?

Comment: That is something like a link or shortcut to the program. You can define them yourself.

Comment: Note those firefox shortcuts were created in version 10.0.

Comment: What do You mean? After You click the shortcut on the panel You can delete it. Or You can add Your own. Delete the unwanted shortcut, and then create Your own named Forefox, and set it's target to Your wanted firefox executable.

Comment: Clarify what "add activator" means. I do not see a menu item containing "Activator" when I right click the bar.